# Loop with dynamic table name and where clause stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to update records and insert their audits to audit table.

For this purpose stored procedure waiting for above variables.

`@m_obj_id INT,
 @m_obj_code NVARCHAR(250),
 @m_f_code NVARCHAR(250),
 @m_nv NVARCHAR(4000),
 @m_last_mod_by INTEGER,
 @table_name SYSNAME,
 --@where_clause NVARCHAR(4000)`

Stored procedure formatting these variables as;

```
UPDATE @table_name SET @m_f_code=@m_nv WHERE id=@m_obj_id
```

And at last part inserting into audit.

I can use it with doing `SELECT CONCAT` and copying all the rows then execute.

But my goal is here not expecting `@m_obj_id` from user and replace it `@where_clause`. And use this `@where_clause` to get ids inside.

So far I tried;

```
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @RecordId int = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'
      SELECT @RecordId = MIN(id)
      FROM ' + @table_name + '
      WHERE id > @RecordId AND (' + @where_clause + ')
      IF @RecordId IS NULL BREAK
      SET @m_obj_id = @RecordId'
Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

But couldnt get far with it.

Then I tried something like;

```
DECLARE @RowsToProcess  int
DECLARE @CurrentRow     int
DECLARE @SelectCol1     int

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = N'
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), col1 int )  
INSERT into @table1 (col1) SELECT id FROM ' + @table_name + ' Where ' + @where_clause + '
SET @RowsToProcess=@@ROWCOUNT'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
N'@RowsToProcess INT OUTPUT', @RowsToProcess OUTPUT

SET @CurrentRow=0
WHILE @CurrentRow<@RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
        DECLARE @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @sql2 = N'
        SET @m_obj_id =
        (SELECT col1
        FROM @table1
        WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow)'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql2
```

But still no luck.

Can I achieve this any how? I am trying to do this for more than it should be.
Thanks all.

Comment: Things like `Where ' + @where_clause + '` are terrifyingly open to injection. Having a completely unparsed, unquoted, unchecked value being passed to dynamic SQL is basically leaving the door wide open for someone to inject into your server. I think we need to know a little more on the broader scope here and fix the major security flaw you have.

Comment: Thanks for warning. I can come back to security after acheiving this. This is my top goal right now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, to be honest, that this is an [XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/). But you need to consider the security as you build the solution. With something like this, if you don't then you're going to just have to rebuild everything again afterwards.

Comment: I really understand your concern. But I need to know if I can do that in this way. If I can achieve this and understand how to do it, it will be no problem to rebuild again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Thanks everyone for responding.

I used a temp table like

```
DECLARE @RowsToProcess INTEGER
DECLARE @CurrentRow INTEGER
DECLARE @SelectCol1 INTEGER

CREATE TABLE #tmp (RowID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), col1 int)

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = N'
INSERT into #tmp (col1) SELECT id FROM ' + @table_name + ' Where ' + @where_clause + '
SET @RowsToProcess=@@ROWCOUNT'
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
N'@RowsToProcess INT OUTPUT', @RowsToProcess OUTPUT

SET @CurrentRow=0
WHILE @CurrentRow<@RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
        SET @m_obj_id =
        (SELECT col1
        FROM #tmp
        WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow)

        Do stuff....
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-dynamic way to implement dynamic filtering on sql is the following:

`where id=@m_obj_id or @m_obj_id is null`

For a LOT of more details on how to choose between dynamic and non-dynamic sql on this, I recommend [this article by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Comment: But I am also getting table name dynamic. So it will not allow me to just put id on where clause.